# Como quitar el subrayado verde de ortografía en el código para pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Me molesta el subrayado verde que aparece abajo de casi todas las palabras que hay en una cadena o nombre de variables, parametros en español.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas creo:

- **Instalando el plugin [Hunspell](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10275-hunspell)**. Para más información puedes checar la [ayuda de WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/spellchecking.html#dictionaries) (aunque creo que está disponible para otros IDE's también)
- **Eliminando la funcionalidad de Spell Checker**:
  `Settings`/`Editor`/`Inspections`/`Spelling` y desactivar `Typo` o sólo algunos de sus módulos.
- **Agregando el diccionario de español**:

  1. Descarga los archivos [aquí](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7851-spell-checker-spanish-dictionary).
  2. Descomprime el zip.
  3. Dentro de la carpeta descomprimida en `src/dict` hay un archivo que dice spanish.0 y contiene muchas palabras en español, cambia su extensión a `.dic`.
  4. En PyCharm adentro de `Settings`/`Editor`/`Spelling`, en donde dice "Custom Dictionaries", agrega el archivo `spanish.dic` mencionado antes.
  5. Da click en "Apply" y listo, ahora PyCharm revisará también tu ortografía en español.

Como sugerencia date una vuelta por el [sitio de soporte oficial de JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com)

Comment: El plugin [Hunspell](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10275-hunspell) también te ayuda a corregir ortografía y creo que es la forma más fácil de hacer esto.
Para más información puedes checar la [ayuda de WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/spellchecking.html#dictionaries) (aunque creo que está disponible para otros IDE's también)

Answer (score 2):

**En las ultimas versiones de Pycharm o IntelliJ IDEA:**

`Settings`/`Editor`/`Inspections`/`Proofreading` y desactivar `Typo`

Answer (score 1):

de aquí https://github.com/EOM/Spell-Checking-PHPStorm-Spanish-dic-UTF8 descargas el diccionario para pycharm no importa que diga phpstorm ese sirve, y acá https://apuntes-snicoper.readthedocs.io/es/latest/editors/pycharm/spell_check_pycharm.html
te dice como debes instalarlo y voalá..!

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/339454)

Answer (score 1):

En PyCharm 2022.1.2 (Community Edition), hacer lo siguiente:

File --> Setting --> Natural Languages, a la ventana derecha aparece un cuadro Languages: donde solo esta English (USA), debajo de ello hay una opcion con el signo "+", hacer click ahí, y buscas Español, lo eliges y Apply y Ok, y queda instalado el diccionario en español.

by Per